# FontFactory (lowagie), Java, getting java.io.EOFException when trying to use Greek-Regular

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, internationalization, itext

I am using com.lowagie.text.FontFactory to register Greek Font to use in a PDF file. But, while registering itself I am getting java.io.EOFException.I would appreciate if anyone may have any insight into this. Thanks

```
FontFactory.register("/classes/fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf","Greek-Regular");
```

Error Stack:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.EOFException
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.readStandardString(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.getAllNames(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.gxs.activefoundation.delegate.DefaultPdfReportDelegateImpl.<clinit>(DefaultPdfReportDelegateImpl.java:212)
```

Comment: Are you working for MindTree on behalf of GXS (OpenText)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is invalid, for the following reasons:

1. You are using my name in your code (I am the Lowagie known from the `com.lowagie` packages). This means that you're using an obsolete version of iText that contains plenty of known bugs that have been fixed **in the last five years.**
2. I've written a proof of concept (POC) using your code snippet in **a recent version of iText** and I can't reproduce the problem.

For the POC, I have downloaded LiberationSans-Regular.ttf from this site: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Sans

I have copy pasted your code snippet and I've taken a simple Greek word to write a small standalone app named [`LiberationSans`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/fonts/LiberationSans). The resulting PDF looks like this: [LiberationSans.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/LiberationSans.pdf) (please check if it shows the Greek word for "Brides").

No exception was encountered:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("LiberationSans.pdf"));
document.open();
FontFactory.register("resources/fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf","Greek-Regular");
Font f = FontFactory.getFont("Greek-Regular", "Cp1253", true);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("\u039d\u03cd\u03c6\u03b5\u03c2", f);
document.add(p);
```

Note that Liberation Sans isn't a Greek font as you claim. It's a font that contains a number of glyphs, *among others* glyphs from the Greek alphabet. Also note that you may want to replace `"Cp1253"` in my example with `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` (this results in more future-proof PDFs).

Long story short: there is a reason why we advise people not to use old versions of iText. Please read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq for more info.